# DIVITIS and using multiple classes

Tags: css

I created many basic classes in CSS, like "rounded", "hidden", "red", "floated", etc... and I use them like if they were LEGO pieces, in order to get the desired result. Why? Because my sites are rendered dinamically, and they may have multiple options. I did not want to create one single class for each possible combination, so I decided to make multiple classes and assign each div for, five or even six different classes. On the other hand, I heard about the DIVITIS issue. I know all the divs I use are neccessary. But my question is:
**Is any of those things a problem? I mean, for rendering it on different devices, or render-time, etc...**

***Use example:***

```
<div class="block spgreen toprounded">
<div class="boxnm left nmquart blue mkPln btn topLrounded"><h1 class="pdg txtCenter">Inicio</h1></div>
<div class="boxnm left nmquart green mkPln btn active"><h1 class="pdg txtCenter">Navegar</h1></div>
<div class="boxnm left nmquart orange mkPln btn"><h1 class="pdg txtCenter">Aprender</h1></div>
<div class="boxnm left nmquart red mkPln btn topRrounded"><h1 class="pdg txtCenter">Compartir</h1></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Each css class has no more than 5 attributes.

**EDIT 2:**
I based my design on "blocks" and "boxes". Blocks have overflow auto, and boxes are always floated. They can have 4 different sizes (width): 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%.
Then I created a list of "magic properities", like: shadow, rounded, and so on... in order to control all the stuff as I. The question is if this can be "wrong" for google to index my pages, or for android phones to render it, or or or...

*Some css could be:*

```
div.block{ /* Block lines (will contain floated boxes) */
 position:relative;
 overflow:auto;
}
div.box{
 position:relative;
 margin:.5%; /* +1% (both-sides) */
}
 div.box.nm{
 margin:0;
}

/* Position */
.center{
 margin:.5% auto !important;
}
.left{
 float:left;
}
.right{
 float:right;
 text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: we'd have a better idea if you shared the CSS as well.

Comment: Re "dynamic rendering". Are you saying that, for a particular div, the look/color etc of the div are setup through config by a user or something?

Comment: @JonEgerton yes... I mean this because the content is shown in a different way depending on its type, its length, etc... and this is decided by the script, after analysing it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I prefer to name css class for what they are, rather than what they look like, eg:

```
<div class="menu">...
<label class="caption">...
```

I would then create a class definition that sets red, and set all the classes to it.

eg .menu, .menu .caption{color:red};

etc etc.

That way you can define a completely different style and the css naming stays true. If you've got classes called `red`, `rounded` and so on, you're stuck with that styling, or else the names become meaningless.

Of course, this might not tie in with your "dynamic rendering", but you've not said what that entails.

Answer (score 3):

It's not about Divitis as such, I suppose. Classical (well, more-o-less...) definition of [divitis](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/03/fight-div-itis-and-class-itis-with-the-960-grid-system/) is about using wrappers where they're not required. When someone uses too much generic containers, defining their semantics with classes, it's called *classitis* actually. )

But I would like to note another problem here: with this convention you actually moved CSS job (styling)... back into HTML. For example, if you need to change the color of some block, you don't touch your CSS files - you edit HTML itself (swapping 'red' class for 'orange' one). I don't think it's how CSS and HTML are supposed to collaborate, to say the least. )

Instead in our environment we use logical blocks, but they are just it - logical blocks. And we're not alone in this: if you closely examine conventions of Twitter Bootstrap framework, you'll see the same approach, I guess. Logical blocks in HTML, styling in CSS - and, of course, quite sparingly used generic blocks. One telling example, as for me, is Bootstrap's styling of icons: when `<i>` elements are used instead of more generic `spans`.

Comment: Well, but there is another part I did not say: all the HTML is generated by PHP functions, which creates boxes depending on several parameters of colour, size, etc... and the idea is: If I wanted to edit my page, I just had to edit the php file which generates HTML (styled in CSS). The problem: could this way of generating content to the user be wrong in any way? (browser compatibility, rendering, etc)...

Comment: @Kenedy Do you really consider it a benefit if you need to edit PHP file to change _style_? As for your direct question, I don't think it may lead to immediate negative effects (a style is a style is a style, after all), but I don't think it'd be easy to maintain and update this site - especially as the time passes...

Comment: Then I will try to use Jon's method, it looks cleaner. Thank you for sharing knowledge :)